# How to find all type of scripts attached to gameobjects in the scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    static List<string> scriptsNames = new List<string>();
    
    [MenuItem("Window/Autocomplete Searchbar/AssetDatabase Search Example")]
    static void Init()
    {
        GetWindow<AssetDatabaseSearchExample>("AssetDatabase Example").Show();
    
        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
        foreach (MonoBehaviour script in scripts)
        {
            Type scriptType = script.GetType();
            var scope = scriptType.Namespace;
            if (scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))
            {
                scriptsNames.Add(scriptType.Name);
            }
            //Debug.Log(script.GetType().FullName + " is used within " + script.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
```

The goal is to find all the scripts and the belonging GameObjects and show it by list or maybe a Dictionary<GameObject, script>.

Comment: Does the above code work? If not then what is wrong with it? Be specific about what you're asking for help with.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the above code is not working because it's looking for only MonoBehaviour type scripts.  but in my project the current project I have only editor type scripts and even a script for example public class AutocompleteSearchField and it's not mono and no editor but have OnGUI in it.  I want to get all the gameobjects in the hierarchy with scripts and any type of scripts.  not only mono and not only editor.

Comment: use [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) then which is the most generic "thing" attached to a `GameObject` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untesetd code, will test properly later,

I would do something like

```
var monobaviours = gameobject.GetComponents<Monobehaviour>();
```

to get all the custom monobehaviour scripts, or simply

```
var compoments = gameobject.GetComponents<Component>();
```

Which should get you all components of any type attached to a particular gameobject

If you want all of them in a scene you can do something like this

```
Dictionary<GameObject, list<Type>> scriptsDict = new();
var allGameObjects = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>(); 
foreach(var go in allGameObjects)
{
    var monobaviours = gameobject.GetComponents<Monobehaviour>();
    scriptsDict.Add(go, monobaviours.select(m => typeof(m)).ToList(); // off my head, may need tinkering
}
```

or if you just want the scrtipts as actual instances

```
Dictionary<GameObject, list<MonoBehaviour>> scriptsDict = new();
var allGameObjects = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>()); 
foreach(var go in allGameObjects)
{        
    var monobaviours = gameobject.GetComponents<Monobehaviour>();
    scriptsDict.Add(go, monobaviours.ToList());
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your `Type scriptType = script.GetType(); var scope = scriptType.Namespace; if(scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))` solution to that?
I suppose you could alternativley have all your scripts impliments an interface and do `GetComponents(typeof(IMyScriptInterface));`